# Covert xls to xlsx in python

Tags: python, excel

I am relatively new to programming/using python, and am trying to convert an .xls file to .xlsx. I found an answer to this problem previously, and someone created this:

```
import xlrd
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook as openpyxlWorkbook

xlsBook = xlrd.open_workbook("input.xls")
workbook = openpyxlWorkbook()

for i in xrange(0, xlsBook.nsheets):
    xlsSheet = xlsBook.sheet_by_index(i)
    workbook.create_sheet()
    sheet.title = xlsSheet.name

    for row in xrange(0, xlsSheet.nrows):
        for col in xrange(0, xlsSheet.ncols):
            sheet.cell(row=row+1, column=col+1).value = xlsSheet.cell_value(row, col)

workbook.save("output.xlsx")
```

However, it runs but I do not get any output. When I tried workbook.save i only ended up with an empty workbook.

Any suggestions??

Comment: Are you running `workbook.save` or `workbook.save()`?

Comment: Might want to try reading xls file into pandas then writing it out to xlsx....

Comment: you can specify a filename and file extension in the workbook.save statement like: `workbook.save('outputfile.xlsx')

check the openpyxl documentation: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/#sample-code

Comment: Thanks! Yes i was actually doing it that way workbook.save('outputfile.xlsx'), and when i did that all i got was an empty xlsx file :(

Comment: I don't see the definition for the variable `sheet` anywhere so I'm guessing the `for` loop isn't running at all, what is `xlsBook.nsheets`?